# Reduce NotoSansCJK font line spacing?

Tags: android, cjk

I use NotoSansCJKsc.otf (思源黑体) in my APP, and the Chinese character's line spacing is too large:

[image]

How do I reduce the line spacing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest < android:includeFontPadding="false" >